# Chartjs - onAnimationComplete fires before the animation actually completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

My problem is that the event `onAnimationComplete` fires before the chart actually finished drawing.

I am use ASP.NET MVC.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="scanedTodayChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var scanedTodayChartCtx = document.getElementById("scanedTodayChart").getContext("2d");
var scanedTodayChart = new Chart(scanedTodayChartCtx, {
    type: 'pie',

    data: {
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "White",
        ],
        datasets: [
        {
            data: [10, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#DA1A32",
                "#F0FFFF"
            ],
            borderWidth: false,
            borderColor: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        cutoutPercentage: 90,
    },
    borderColor: '#DA1A32',
    fullWidth: true,
    onAnimationComplete: new function () {
        alert('onAnimationComplete')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you did not define an animation. Try [this example](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/AnimationCallbacks/progress-bar.html) found at [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-animation-configuration).

```
var scanedTodayChart = new Chart(scanedTodayChartCtx, {
    type: 'pie',

    data: {
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "White",
        ],
        datasets: [
        {
            data: [10, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#DA1A32",
                "#F0FFFF"
            ],
            borderWidth: false,
            borderColor: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        cutoutPercentage: 90,
        animation: {
            duration: 2000,
            onProgress: function(animation) {
                $progress.attr({
                    value: animation.animationObject.currentStep / animation.animationObject.numSteps,
                });
            },
            onComplete: function(animation) {
                alert('onAnimationComplete')
            }
        }
    },
    borderColor: '#DA1A32',
    fullWidth: true,
});
```

Comment: now i have a different problem, i added a text in the middle of the pie on complete. Now when i hover the chart, the chart is "re-created" and the text disappears and re-creates. Setting tooltipes.enabled=false didnt solve it. Creating the text on "onanimationProgress" did solve it, but doesnt feel like the right solution